# Is it natural to use 'savvy' to modify 'doctor'?

Tags: word-usage, word-choice, difference

The word 'savvy' seems to be more about experience and knowledge according to *[CambridgeDictionary](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/us/dictionary/english/savvy#:%7E:text=having%20or%20showing%20practical%20knowledge%20and%20experience)*:

> savvy: having or showing practical knowledge and experience.

In the spirit of that, it seems reasonable to replace the word 'astute' by 'savvy' in the following sentence (quoted from [differencebee](https://differencebee.com/shrewd-and-astute/#:%7E:text=The%20problem%20with%20motor%20neurone%20disease%20is%20they%20don%27t%20know%20when%20it%20starts.%20People%20go%20into%20hospital%20having%20fallen%20but%20get%20wrapped%20up%20and%20sent%20away%2C%20unless%20they%27re%20seen%20by%20an%20incredibly%20astute%20doctor.%20It%20is%20only%20when%20several%20things%20begin%20to%20go%20wrong%20that%20it%27ll%20be%20diagnosed.)).

> The problem with motor neurone disease is they don't know when it starts. People go into hospital having fallen but get wrapped up and sent away, unless they're seen by an incredibly **astute** doctor. It is only when several things begin to go wrong that it'll be diagnosed.

So, is it natural to say/write this? (See the following)

> The problem with motor neurone disease is they don't know when it starts. People go into hospital having fallen but get wrapped up and sent away, unless they're seen by an incredibly **savvy** doctor. It is only when several things begin to go wrong that it'll be diagnosed.

Comment: That word sounds unnatural to me in that context.  I would rather say "unless they are seen by a very good doctor".

Comment: @JohnGordon What about 'an experienced doctor'?

Comment: Note that Cambridge labels _savvy_ as 'informal'.

Comment: @KateBunting I don’t think the problem in this context is the level of formality. The tone of the rest of the passage is not extremely formal, so it fits. It’s that *savvy* has different connotations than *astute*.

Comment: On a side-note, both “motor neurone disease” and “go into hospital” sound incorrect, at least in American English. I think “into hospital” is correct British English, though.

Comment: @Davislor - That's what the condition is called in the UK.

Comment: @KateBunting Ah, okay. Makes sense.

Comment: Astralbee's answer is correct, but if you want to use a more informal idiom, you could say "unless their doctor is incredibly *on-the-ball*" or "unless they're seen by an incredibly *canny* doctor".

Answer (score 12, accepted):

'Astute' and 'savvy' are not exactly interchangeable.

'Astute' is more synonymous with *wisdom*, being mentally sharp, discerning.

'Savvy' is a much more informal word, but also implies more *practical wisdom acquired through experience* than education and intellect. Terms like 'street-wise' come to mind. For example, someone who is 'business-savvy' is good at making choices that earn them money. You tend to hear the word used to describe people who worked their way up in business from nothing, rather than people who studied business or economics at university and acquired their business knowledge formally.

As doctors study long and hard to get their qualifications, describing one as 'savvy' doesn't feel quite right. An *astute* doctor would be one that perhaps paid exceptional attention to detail and was that little bit sharper than others. That isn't conveyed by the word 'savvy'. The latter makes me think of shrewdness in business, money-saving, shortcut-taking, and other things that you definitely wouldn't want a doctor to do.

Comment: I agree in general, but think it would be acceptable to describe a doctor as "savvy" if you're referring to practical wisdom picked up from seeing patients and dealing with their real-world problems, rather than medical-school wisdom and clinical procedures.

Comment: @StuartF The locals where I live prefer a doctor that is a bit aged, believing that such a doctor has more practical experience.

Comment: Worth noting, maybe that 'savvy' is regarded as _informal_ and would not really be appropriate for academic or formal writing.

Comment: @StuartF It's certainly 'acceptable', especially if you were suggesting they were savvy in other ways. But the OP is asking if they can exchange the word 'astute' for it, and the focus of my answer is on the difference between them. An astute doctor would be one that perhaps paid exceptional attention to detail and was that little bit sharper than others. That isn't conveyed by the word 'savvy'. It make me think of money-saving, shortcut-taking, and other things that you definitely wouldn't want a doctor to do. I stand by my answer.

Comment: @Astralbee - If I heard of a 'savvy doctor' I might think that they had been worldly-wise enough to marry the son or daughter of the chief surgeon at the hospital where they were working, or had bought a yacht from kickbacks from drug companies for prescribing their products.

Comment: @MichaelHarvey That sounds more like a corrupt doctor to me.

Comment: @Astralbee - I thought it was common in [some countries](https://www.propublica.org/article/doctors-prescribe-more-of-a-drug-if-they-receive-money-from-a-pharma-company-tied-to-it).

Comment: Totally agree. I guess one way *savvy* might work is, if the medical establishment doesn’t recognize a problem yet, but a doctor knows about it from first-hand experience, or if the doctor understands her patients well enough to know what they really mean.

Comment: I would expect "savvy" to describe something other than working medical knowledge when applied to a doctor. Maybe he knows medical billing, maybe he knows all the local politicians, whatever.

Comment: What about 'shrewd'? Can I use 'shrewd' here?

Answer (score -1):

It's perfectly natural, but it is more informal.

It is not really a synonym for 'astute'. 'Savvy' implies knowledge, whereas 'astute' implies an ability and willingness to use knowledge.